# Java array input

Tags: java, arrays

Ok i am kind of new to java, but I did google search for creating methods and got mixed results so i am a bit confused on how to achieve this..
Basically I have an array which will store 20 unique account numbers, no less no more.
In addition to storing the account number i will give the option to the user to store the account balance (money, yes u guessed it this is bank account kind of homework assignment)

So the issue that i am facing is, for the process of the program run time, if the user decides to add 15accounts, i want to know how can i put the consequent accno entry in to the next free array index . and also trigger a message to say no more accounts cannot be added after capping the number of accounts at 20

```
public static void addAccount()
{

    int i=0;
    String accno, input;
    double accbal;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] accnums = new String[20];
    System.out.print("Enter the account number:");
    accno = sc.nextLine();

    if(accno.length() != 9) //the accno shld not be more than 9.
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong accnum");
    }
    else
    {
       //THis is the part i am not sure how to put the code tks.
    }

    input= accnums[1];
   System.out.println("The value:"+input);//this is just for me to display / test
}
```

Comment: `if(accno.length()<9 | accno.length()>9)`: **First** - You should prefer the non bitwise: `operator||` **2nd**: it returns false if and only if `accno.length == 9` - if this is what you are after: use `operator!=`. **Third**: `length` is a field, not a method in an array. Please try to first compile your code and tell us what difficulties you are facing after you do.

Comment: your 2nd one that is exactly what i want and the accno MUST be 9 char.
As for any errors after compile NOTHING! but the logic is the problem not an error tks

Comment: @JackBoi: Then use `opertator!=` - it is much more readable

Comment: @JackBoi: My apologies regarding the third, I thoguth `accno` was an array. I now see it is a `String`, so it is indeed a method. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest (Though not most efficient, but I don't believe it is an issue here) can be loop and look for a `null`, and place it in the first `null` value:

```
int j;
for (j = 0; j < accnums.length; j++)
  if (accnums[j] == null) break;
if (j==accnums.length)  {
  // error msg, the array is already full
} else { 
  //insert element into index j
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an hashmap instead of an array? Create an Account class with the attributes characterizing. Then create an AccountManager class as a Singleton (http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton). In the ACcountManager add an hashmap private attribute and some methods you will use to add and get account indexed by means of the key.

Comment: hi, probably you have missed the tag 'homework', i havent been thought about hashmap and stuff so if i use that definetly can tell something is fishy.. so ya simple answer to the question will be better.. tks for the reply but will still learn the things that you suggested.

Comment: also this particular question one of the learning objectives is learn how to use an array! :)

Comment: scanner is to get the users input, basically it will read the users input.

Comment: Please avoid giving complete answers (especially unexplained ones) for questions tagged homework. Note that the tag excrept says: `... This lets potential answerers know that they SHOULD guide the student in solving the problem, and SHOULD NOT simply show the complete answer.`

Comment: @Silli: Some code is perfectly fine, just avoid giving a *complete answer*. If you feel a small code sample is needed - it is OK, just make sure the code sample is guiding and not giving a complete answer, and the student still needs to think in order to get his HW right (otherwise - he will not learn from it).